# Column names not displaying correctly

Tags: r

I imported a dataset (Panel) and combined X2 and X3 using the unite function and then transposed the data after reading in another thread that column headers can't be dates:

```
Panel <- read_csv("Panel.csv")

         X2      X3  1.2015   2.2015 3.2015 
1        A       KR  13201    27667  45967
2        A       TW  2601     4669   8399
3        B       KR  4721     9463   15187
4        B       TW  2832     6544   10636

Panel_1 <- Panel %>% unite(X2, X3,X2, sep = " ")

          X2   1.2015   2.2015 3.2015 
1        KR A   13201    27667  45967
2        TW A   2601     4669   8399
3        KR B   4721     9463   15187
4        TW B   2832     6544   10636

Panel_1 <- as.dataframe(t(Panel))
           V1             V2             V3             V4 
 X2       KR A           TW A          KR B            TW B
1.2015    13201          2601          4721            2832
2.2015    27667          4669          9463            6544 
3.2015    45967          8399          15187           10636
```

and then tried to paste the first row (X2) as columns names. However, my column names display only NA

```
colnames(Panel_1) <-paste(Panel_1$X2)

colnames(Panel_1)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA

Panel_1
           NA             NA            NA              NA 
 X2       KR A           TW A          KR B            TW B
1.2015    13201          2601          4721            2832
2.2015    27667          4669          9463            6544 
3.2015    45967          8399          15187           10636

> typeof(Panel$X2)
[1] "character"
> typeof(Panel_1$X2)
[1] "NULL"
```

Comment: Hi @Cheryl, can you share an example of your input data and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to set header=TRUE while reading the file. now all visible in names and View commands

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Load example dataset

```
data("iris")
head(iris)

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Define `id` as values pasted together from first two rows of the dataset

```
id = with(iris, paste0(iris[1,],iris[2,]))
```

Check that id are the values pasted together from the first two rows

```
id
"5.14.9" "3.53"   "1.41.4" "0.20.2" "11"
```

Change the colnames of the dataset to those defined in `id`

```
colnames(iris) = id
```

View that dataset colnames are now the values of the first two rows

```
head(iris)

  5.14.9 3.53 1.41.4 0.20.2     11
1    5.1  3.5    1.4    0.2 setosa
2    4.9  3.0    1.4    0.2 setosa
3    4.7  3.2    1.3    0.2 setosa
4    4.6  3.1    1.5    0.2 setosa
5    5.0  3.6    1.4    0.2 setosa
6    5.4  3.9    1.7    0.4 setosa
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @pomodoro. However when i type that line     id = with(iris, paste0(iris[1,],iris[2,])) , id  doesn't give me the same result. Instead it gives me "c(X2 = 26)c(X3 = 27)" "c(X2 = 47)c(X3 = 48)"  etc. Any ideas on what might be going on?

Comment: It works with the iris dataset. If you cannot extrapolate the above to your own dataset, it must be something to do with your dataset. Although I see you have also changed some of your question since I answered.